# Consulta PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, select

Tengo la tabla materiales, la cual tiene como campos id, usuario, gps, mapa, y brujula. Necesito contar todos los campos gps, mapa y brujula que tengan como valor 1 y cuyo id sea 2 y cuyo usuario no sea admin@correo.es

Como nosé hacer la consulta directamente en SQl estoy haciendo chapuzas, y esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido:

```
$sql = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM materiales WHERE plan = :id AND usuario <> :usuario');
$sql->execute(['id' => 2], 'usuario' => admin@correo.es);
$resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$gpsT=0;
$maaT=0;
...

foreach($resultado as $value)
{
    if($value["gps"] ==1)
    {
        $gpsT++;
    }
    
    if($value["mapa"]==1)
    {
       $mapaT++;
    }

    ...

}
```

Funciona si el usuario no tiene @,aún así no creo que sea lo óptimo, si la tabla tuviese 50 campos sería casi absurdo.

El resultado esperado sería:

[image: tabla del resultado esperado]

Lo que quiero es hacer un count de cada campo (con valor 1) y que meta estos counts en un array que me diga campo valor, siendo el valor 1. Si campo tuviese valor 0, lo tednria que desechar.

¿Alguien me puede ayudara oprtimizar? Gracias

Comment: ¿Necesitas contar todos los registros para `id=2` cuyos `campo1, campo2... campoN` sean **TODOS** igual a 1?. ¿O que **CUALQUIERA** de los `campo1, campo2, ... campoN` sea igual a 1? Lo pregunto porque el enunciado dice lo primero y el código dice lo segundo.

Comment: @aeportugal perdona por la ambigüedad de la pregunta. Te detallo, necesito saber cuántos campo1 son 1, cuántos campo2 son 1 y así … no necesito el conteo general, necesito el conteo de cada campo o columna

Comment: Si en un futuro necesitaras 50 campos, diria que esta mal planteado el modelado de datos. Si hoy te es un problema revisar los campos, quiere decir que deberías crear una tabla de "materiales" (`id_material, nombre, etc.`) y otra tabla de "materiales_usuarios" (`id_material, id_usuario, cantidad?`) (_o algo similar_). A esta técnica se la conoce como [normalización](https://cnx.org/contents/qtZsLi-X@1/Un-ejemplo-simple-de-normalizaci%C3%B3n-de-bases-de-datos-relacionales-hasta-3FN)

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Comment: @Sal agregue el resultado esperado en el post editándolo

Comment: Intenta con `if($value["gps"]===1)`

Comment: @Sal ese código fucniona. el caso es si desde SQL se puede hacer más optimo, para evitar todos esos if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo consigues con *agregación condicional*:

```
SELECT sum( gps = 1 ) gps
     , sum( mapa = 1 ) mapa
  FROM materiales 
  WHERE plan = :id 
    AND usuario <> :usuario
```

Comment: muchas gracias, puedes actualizar la respuesta con el código en php para manejar el resultado?